# Complexity of two nested loops that do not always run

Tags: java, loops, time-complexity

I need to write an answer with the least complexity degree. My questions is regarding nested-loops that do not always run. I have a for loops that iterates N times, depending on length of the string, and searches for a 'char' value. When it finds it, it iterates the loop again from this point onwards, looking for more 'char' values.
 I wrote the following method:

```
public static int subStrMaxC(String s, char c, int k) {
    char[] stringChars=new char[s.length()];
    //System.out.print("the string of the characters is");
    for(int i=0;i<stringChars.length;i++) {
        stringChars[i]=s.charAt(i);
    //  System.out.print(stringChars[i]);
    }
    int count=0;
    int bigcount=0;
    int[] charArray=new int[s.length()];
    for(int i=0;i<stringChars.length;i++) {
            count=0;
            if(stringChars[i]=='c') {
                count++;
                for(int j=i+1;j<stringChars.length;j++) {
                      if(stringChars[j]=='c') {
                            count++;
                            if((count>=2)&&(count<=k+2)) {
                                bigcount++;
                                if(count==k+2) {
                                    count=0;
                                    j=stringChars.length-1;
                                }
                            }
                      }
                }
            }
    }
    return bigcount;
}
```

Since the second loop do not iterate unless the first loop finds a value that meets the condition, I did not know whether the complexity is defined O(n^2)-which is my assumption, as the second loop can, in the worst case run N*(N-i) times- or just O(n), which is what I'm looking for.
Thank you!

Comment: Big O means worst case, ie, when everything runs

Comment: complexity here is O(N^2), are you sure the code is correct? I think the literal 'c' should be c.

Comment: Please explain what your method should do. The current complexity is O(n2), but when you explain your task we can probably say how you can reach the O(n) complexity.

Comment: Hi, thanks for all the comments. I need to receive a string, a char C and a number K, and find out how many sub-strings exist in that string, and are: 1. Begining and ending with char C, 2. Have a maximum K amount of the C char inside the substring(excluding the first and last characters). I hope this is clear. Thank you!

Comment: You simply need to compute the number of C in your string and then you can compute the result value without a loop in loop (I think the computation algorythm is in fact your task).

Comment: I have to admit I'm abit lost doing that.. Obviously finding the amount of C is easy, but I just cant seem to think of any way to compute the amount of options inside the loop.. I'd be happy to receive some more guidance. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I am quite sure this is the best you can do, but of course I may be wrong.  The problem you have with your approach is your limited use of Space Complexity.  With the approach below, you iterate through the string only once (i.e. no 'j' loop which leads to the n squared problem).  Here you build out candidate substrings by using space/memory.  Now you only have to iterate over candidate substrings which has a much lower time complexity than your first approach.

```
public class MaxKSubstring {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String INPUT = "testingwithtees";
    char C = 't';
    int K = 1;

    int count = subStrMaxC(INPUT, C, K);
    System.out.println(count);

}
public static int subStrMaxC(String s, char c, int k) {
    char letters[] = s.toCharArray();
    int valid = 0;
    List<Candidate> candidates = new ArrayList<Candidate>();
    for (int i=0; i< s.length(); i++) {
        if (letters[i] == c)
            candidates.add(new Candidate(k, c));

        for (Candidate candidate : candidates) {
            if (candidate.addLetter(letters[i])) {
                System.out.println(candidate.value);
                valid++;
            }
        }

    }
    return valid;
    }
}

class Candidate {

final int K;
final char C;

public Candidate(int k, char c) {
    super();
    K = k;
    C = c;
}
boolean endsWithC = false;
String value = "";
int kValue = 0;
public boolean addLetter(char letter) {
    endsWithC = false;
    value = value+letter;
    if (letter == C) {
        kValue++;
        endsWithC = true;
    }
    return endsWithC && kValue <= K+2 && value.length() > 1;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**O(n) best case, 
O(n<sup>2</sup>) worst case**

I'm not sure what you mean by the least complexity. If you are referring to the best case, that would be O(n) performance. (The parent loop iterates only and the nested loops are never iterated) since the matching case:

```
if(stringChars[i]=='c')
```

Is always false. However, the **worst case** time complexity which is usually what we're referring to is O(n<sup>2</sup>), owing to the fact that the condition `if(stringChars[i]=='c')` returns `true` every single time.